# Laravel validation not allow to be false all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am a beginnerwith the Laravel framework. I am struggling to declare validation of request data. I have some checkboxes in the form, and at least one of the checkboxes must be selected to submit to the database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="has_a_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_a_type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="has_b_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_b_type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="has_c_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_c_type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="has_d_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_d_type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="has_e_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_e_type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="has_f_type" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_f_type" value="1">
```

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request = $request->validate([
        'form_id' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'has_a_type' => 'required',
        'has_b_type' => 'required',
        'has_c_type' => 'required',
        'has_d_type' => 'required',
        'has_e_type' => 'required',
        'has_f_type' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

When users submit the form, they must select the form type at least once. How can I do that? I can check by adding the following code under the validate code.

```
if (!($request['has_a_type'] || $request['has_b_type'] || $request['has_c_type'] || $request['has_d_type'] || $request['has_e_type'] || $request['has_f_type'])) {
    return ...->withError();
}
```

But I wonder if there is a way to check this invalidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two possible solutions for your problem:

**One is using [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-without-all)**

```
$request = $request->validate([
...
'has_a_type' => 'required_without_all','has_b_type','has_c_type' ...
'has_b_type' => ...
...
]);
```

---

**Another better solution is passing data in array**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="has_type[]" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" name="has_type[]" value="b">
...
```

```
$request = $request->validate([
...
'has_type' => 'required',
])
;
```

> ***NOTE:*** In both solutions you will need to remove those hidden fields: `<input type="hidden" name="has_a_type" value="0">`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validation rule to check if at least one checkbox is selected. First, generate a new rule using the following command.

```
php artisan make:rule AtLeastOneCheckbox
```

This will create a new rule class in the `app/Rules` directory. In the `AtLeastOneCheckbox` class, you can define the condition for the rule in the `passes` method.

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class AtLeastOneCheckbox implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Check if at least one checkbox is selected
        return collect($value)->contains(1);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'At least one checkbox must be selected.';
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this rule to validate the checkboxes in your controller. This will ensure that at least one checkbox is selected when submitting the form.

```
use App\Rules\AtLeastOneCheckbox;

public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'form_id' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'has_a_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
        'has_b_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
        'has_c_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
        'has_d_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
        'has_e_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
        'has_f_type' => ['required', new AtLeastOneCheckbox],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching the docs I saw the [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-without-all) rule which might be what you need.

> required_without_all:foo,bar,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

You specify the other checkboxes in the `bar,...` argument list, something like

```
    'has_a_type' => 'required_without_all','has_b_type','has_c_type' ...
```

I must admit that I've not used this rule myself, it just looks like it might be a good use for it, but it will only work when you remove the hidden fields and just use the checkboxes.